# Unable to Save Flask_WTF Form Data to DB using BootStrap Modal & JQuery

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have created a basic form in flask using Flask-WTF and using Bootstrap4 Modal + Jquery to save the data to DB on the backend. I am able to save data directly via html page but when I try to update same HTML page form via JQuery inside a modal popup, its does not get through.

Below is code for my flask view.py

```
@bare_blueprint.route('/add_group', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_group():
    form = AddGroupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        group = request.form['group']
        groups = [(group.group) for group in dev_group.query.order_by('group') ]
        if group in groups:
            flash(u'Group Name Already Listed, Please choose a unique group name')
        else:
            form.group.data = ''
            new_group = dev_group(group)
            db.session.add(new_group)
            db.session.commit()
            flash(u'Group Added Successfully!')
    return render_template('add_group.html', form=form)
```

Which is connected to my HTML page (which is working perfectly). Code for the same is as below-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1> Add New Group </h1>
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<form method='POST'>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.group.label }} {{ form.group(id='groupname')}}
{{ form.submit(id='submit')}}

{% endblock %}
```

Now I have a third page, which is like dashboard page of my app where I have created a button which throws this form inside the modal popup. I am trying to add group to my database via that modal form.

Here is the HTML & JQuery code for my modal -

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Add group
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Group</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" >Group Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupname" placeholder="Enter Group Name">
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Group</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script> $(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    var group = $('#groupname').val();

        req = $.ajax({
      url : '/add_group',
      type : 'POST',
      data : {group : group},
        })
        req.done(function(data) {
      $('#groupname').html(data);
        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});
</script>
```

I do not see any error in developers tools after submitting the form, just my HTML form page is returned.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, `flask-wtf` provides CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) protection, which requires that you either disable it, or better, include

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

at the top of your HTML form.

See https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think {{ form.hidden_tag() }} in my code is doing the same thing. I still added the added the tag but results is same.